# Show Tool Tip When a certain Button is Held down & Removetool Tip when button is Released / Up

Tags: autohotkey

need help creating an example script of tool tip

Scenario : when i held down / press down CTRL a tooltip will appear , the tooltip will only dissappear if

1. the CTRL modifier is released
2. when CTRL key is held down then ANY KEYS is triggered / combine ( ex. Ctrl + A B C so forth ) or any modifier keys like ( Ctrl + SHIFT  ) ( ctrl + alt ) ( ctrl + alt + shift ) so forth

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~LControl::
    ToolTip, LControl,,, 1
    SetTimer RemoveTooltip1, 50
return

~LControl Up:: 
    SetTimer RemoveTooltip1, off
    ToolTip,,,, 1
return

RemoveTooltip1:
    If (A_PriorKey != "LControl")
        ToolTip,,,, 1
return
```

For all modifier keys:

```
; List of keys to bind
keys := "LControl,RControl,LShift,RShift,LAlt,RAlt,LWin,RWin"

; bind the keys to keypress_handler
Loop, parse, keys, `,
{
    hotkey, ~%A_Loopfield%, keypress_handler1
    hotkey, ~%A_Loopfield% Up, keypress_handler2
}

keypress_handler1:
    ThisKeyLabel := StrReplace(A_ThisHotkey, "~")
    ToolTip, %ThisKeyLabel%,,, 1
    SetTimer RemoveTooltip1, 50
return

keypress_handler2:
    SetTimer RemoveTooltip1, off
    ToolTip,,,, 1
return

RemoveTooltip1:
    ThisKeyLabel := StrReplace(A_ThisHotkey, "~")
    If (A_PriorKey != ThisKeyLabel)
        ToolTip,,,, 1
return
```